# Rules for on implicit fields initialization

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, stack

I have recently fixed a bug in an application of mine: the problem was that an object that resides on the stack had a field left uninitialized.

The object had a class declaration of this type:

```
struct A{
    int somefield, someotherfield;
    A(): someotherfield(0) {}
}
```

and when declaring a local variable (like `A var;` in a function), `somefield` was left uninitialized, and so a read of it would return a randomish value.

I was certain that fields of a class, which don't appear in the constructor initialization list, would always get initialized by a synthesized trivial constructor (in the case of an int, a zero value). Evidently I am wrong.

So what are the general rules about implicit field initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- classes and structs are initialized by contructor
- Basic types int double char short ... are not initialized and contain random numbers
- Pointers are not initialized and point to random positions
- arrays of classes or structs cause each element to be initialized by its constructor
- arrays of basic types or pointers are random.

Comment: what about arrays? same rules for each element?